# Gas line pressure drop after 1 month

Tags: natural-gas

I had a natural gas line installed to my kitchen for a gas cook top.  The line was connected past the main regulator. After installing the line, the installers ran a pressure check at 10 psi.  It held pressure while they were here and through the next several days.  Due to labor shortages the county inspector came about a month latter.  At this time the gage was reading 0.  The inspector said that means there is a leak and failed the inspection.  The installer said they will come back and pump up the line and reschedule the inspection.  Should the pressure have held for a month? Does this indicate maybe a slow leak? The installer who is a larger local company that did my hvac system, said it was just the time between the inspection and installation.

Comment: It should not leak at all, zero.

Comment: If the line leaked air over a month, it'll also leak gas when the gas is turned on. That's why the inspector failed it. Don't forget, this was only a month, there will be gas in that line for years to come. You don't want some leaking out every day. Bad for the gas bill. _Really_ bad for breathing. _Exceptionally_ bad should there be a spark in the house.

Comment: Is this the only line in the house or is this line teed off from other lines you were using?

Comment: Could've been the gauge that leaked. It doesn't take much volume loss to lose 10PSI. I wouldn't be surprised if that would be a common occurrence over a month's time.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I will work with the installers on getting it fixed or find someone else to do the work.  The line is teed off just past the main regulator.  They put a valve at the tee outside and another valve under the counter where the cooktop is.  The valve at the   tee is closed, so it is isolated from the gas line.  The pressure check fitting is installed under the counter.  The installer pressurized the line from there.

Comment: How can I be sure the system is safe.  When the installer checked it it held 10 psi for at least 30 minutes, and per the installer that is all that is required.  It seems that that is not really enough in ensure the system is leak free. 
If they recharge the line and the inspector comes in within a couple of days It likely will  pass.    But that does not seem to indicate it is safe.  The run is about 30 feet, and is black pipe.

Comment: @BenMarkel if you fill up your gas tank, and it empty a month later due to leaking ? Certain things are made not to leak at all, no when and if.

Comment: Air conditioning operates at 300PSI and it is made not to leak.

Comment: Ruskes, thanks.  I think I will be getting a different installer to redo the work. I agree that there should be no leaks and the pressure should hold indefinitely.  Since it is natural gas there is no tank to run out just an endless supply if gas to leak.

Answer (score 1):

There should be *zero* leaks from a gas line. Period.

Any leakage will:

1. Increase your gas bill
2. Be bad for your health, including:

   1. Breathing natural gas isn't good for you.
   2. Having natural gas collect in an area where there could be a spark or open flame tends to lead to things going **boom**. This is generally considered a Bad Thing™.

It *is* possible that there is a leak at the pressure gauge, so be sure to test with a 2nd gauge to ensure that wasn't the problem, before tearing everything else apart to redo the whole line.

---

A collection of the wisdom posted in the comments.

Comment: Thank You.  Contractor is coming back out to go back over everything.  The bad part is if the inspector came out the day after the contractor pressurized the lines it would have looked good and everything would have passed and I would have not known there was a problem.  Good thing the inspections were so slow.  Seems like they are back on schedule now.